# jasper server 5.6 active directory authentication not working

Tags: spring-security, active-directory, ldap, jasperserver

I'm authentication jasper server 5.6 to ldap active directory.ldapAuthenticationProvider bean configurations are ok.(userDnPatterns working).but server couldn't search in usersearch bean.this is my userSearch configuration.Am I correctly put values to constructor-arg ?

```
 <bean id="userSearch"
      class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
  <constructor-arg index="0"><value>(sAMAccountName={0})</value></constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg index="1"><value>sAMAccountName={0},ou=IT Service Accounts</value></constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg index="2"><ref local="ldapContextSource"/></constructor-arg>
  <property name="searchSubtree"><value>true</value></property>
</bean>
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should not use "sAMAccountName" as first parameter (index=0), as that parameter is the Directory search base.

If you want to use the default search base, leave the value blank.

Now, the second parameter, tells jasper (or any app that uses the FilterBasedLdapUserSearch method) how to search for the user, and what user should the app use to finally bind to the directory.

The fiter you specified on "index=1" would only work if AD has users DN's in the form: 
DN: sAMAccountName=user,ou=IT Service Accounts, .....

Now, AD's default user DN's are more like: "CN=Full Name,CN=Users,....", so, in your case, you should be using only (sAMAccountName={0}) in the "FilterBasedLdapUserSearch" method, and then modify "LdapAuthenticationProvider" method to specify "userDnPatterns", like this:

`<bean id="ldapAuthenticationProvider"`

`class="org.springframework.security.providers.ldap.LdapAuthenticationProvider">`

`<constructor-arg><bean class="org.springframework.security.providers.ldap.authenticator.BindAuthenticator">`

`<constructor-arg><ref local="ldapContextSource"/></constructor-arg>`

`<property name="userDnPatterns"/>`

`<list> <value>CN={0},ou=IT Service Accounts</value> </list> </bean> </bean>`

Of course, you should match this more closely to your setup, this is only an example.

Comment: Hi thanks for amswering.But still same problem.No error logs.But can't acess using AD.